# ERD to relation schema: How to convert this self-referencing m-to-m relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

#### Question that was given

A location can have multiple category labels. A category has a hierarchy structure, and it has multiple subcategories, e.g. Category is Education, and subcategories are University, High School, Pre-school, etc.

Given this ERD:

[image: ER Diagram]

how do I properly convert it into relation schema?

#### My solution

- Location(**location_id**, address, name, description, x_coords, y_coords)

Because of many-to-many relationship between Location and Category:

- LocationCategory(**location_id**, **category_name**)

**Category has a self-referencing many-to-many relationship**

- Category(**category_name**)
- Subcategory(**subcategory_name**, **category_name**)

I think my solution above is wrong. The problem with my relation schema is LocationCategory can only store the category_name but not the subcategory_name. With the category_name itself, in Subcategory, it is not possible to capture the subcategory_name if that category has multiple subcategories.

I think I have made a mistake with the self-referencing many-to-many relationship in Category. And this Category entity does not have any other attributes. Is there a special way to solve this? i.e. to create the relation schema such that a location is able to be linked to both category and subcategory? Or have I interpreted the diagram wrongly?

Comment: The lines in the diagram say Contain holds the PKs to 2 Categories & the underline under name says it is the Category PK. Category is an entity type, not a relationship type. There is no entity or relationship Subcategory. Why do you have it but not contains? (Rhetorical.) You don't say what is a problem, so what if "Category entity does not have any other attributes"? "solve" what? Find & follow how to map an ERD to DDL in your textbook. Ask a question where you are first unsure or stuck & refer to your textbook. Please don't ask us to rewrite it. Also we can expect all steps are SO faqs.

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh Please don't edit images inline when the text in them should be inline, especially when that text can make the image redundant. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097 It rewards bad questions. Please tell the person to use text, give them that FAQ link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The problem with my relation schema is LocationCategory can only store the category_name but not the subcategory_name."*

Then simply store it, f. e. like this:

[image]

Note: there is no need to store the `cat_id` in the `locationCategory` table, because the `subcat_id` determines the `cat_id`, but for easier querying it can help.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.